# How to use the same UI with multiple java files? ANDROID JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml, setcontentview

I'm a newbie and I'm working on a Unit Converter.

I would like to open the same UI regardless of which button I click(Weight or Length)
*main_activity.xml UI*

[image: activity_main.xml]

Below is the UI I want to open: *activity_conversion.xml UI*

[image: activity_conversion.xml]

And I would like each button in the main_activity to run on a different java class.
So, (minus the main_activity.java and it's .xml file)
I have 1 xml file(activity_conversion.xml) and 2 java files one for each button of the main_activity.xml

*activity_main.xml Weight button*

```
android:onClick="weightPage"
```

*activity_main.xml Length button*

```
android:onClick="lengthPage"
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public void weightPage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WeightActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void lengthPage(View view) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, LengthActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

*Length_Activity.java code for Length button*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversion);
}
```

setContentView() method doesn't work for me:(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `setContentView() method doesn't work for me` for what purpose it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to open the same UI regardless of which button I click(Weight or Length)

You can do that by creating an activity and its layout XML file. And then start that activity via explicit intent like this:

```
//Place this code inside the onClick method
Intent intent = new Intent(SoucreActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

> And I would like each button in the main_activity to run on a different java class.

No, you cannot. All UI elements on a screen are always in the same activity; they cannot run on different java classes. (Unless you are using fragments of which you need not worry about as you are a newbie)

Apparently, you want the two buttons in your main activity to open the same activity. Which you can achieve using intents using the code snippet mentioned above.